# Access $rootScope variable in a directive template?

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable called `state` that's in `$rootScope`, and i want to access that variable in the template left-widget.html of my directive `leftWidget`

```
app.directive('leftWidget', function ($rootScope) {
    'use strict';
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title:'@',
            name:'@'
        },
        templateUrl: '/templates/left-widget.html
    }
});
```

I can't find a way to do it... Any help? Thanks

EDIT: Solved it with a linking function like this:

```
link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
    $scope.state = $rootScope.state;
}
```

Comment: Use a directive controller (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) and `$scope.state = $rootScope.state`, then access `state` in the template.

Comment: i solved it with a linking function 

'link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
            $scope.state = $rootScope.state;
        }'

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv `controller` is more meant to expose an API to other directives. `link` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: I agree. The controller docs were easier to find though and put him in the right direction :)